# starting from a cics program, is it possible to give an instruction (with a specific url) to open a web browser page?

Tags: browser, cobol, cics

My problem is that I have been asked to insert an instruction into a cics program that it can open a web page using a specific url.

Is it possible to give this kind of instruction ?
If yes, can you show me example code ?

Please notice that the program runs on a cics simulator called 'Unikix', which is installed on linux server with an old RedHat distribution still 32bit.

The cics program, in which I have to insert this instruction, is written in Cobol language and it is compiled using Microfocus compiler.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "open a web page using a sepcific URL"? Does that mean that on the client side a web browser should be started with a specific address? Or should the program retrieve some data from the given URL and display it on a CICS map?

Comment: the first one is the issue,
retrieve data from other application is already been done by calling web services
but open a new window into the browser web is the actual request,
do you think it is makeable ?

Comment: There is no asimple solution for this. CICS thinks it is talking to an IBM3270 Terminal - so no way to address a browser on that. Any solution would have to involve a piece of client software - be it the terminal emulation or some custom program that's running on the client and waiting for requests from the CICS side.

Comment: would it be possible to modify an open source 3270 client (of which sources should be available) to add the functionality to intercept the link and open the new window?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the OP indicated he is using a 3270 as the interface point (its a fair assumption but not in the post).  @Riccardo an alternative would be to potentially use a CICS Web interface for the front-end which would make launching a browser session easier.  Looking at their website it appears their COBOL version might be able to use Active X Controls.  Can you give more information on your architecture?  "Inserting an instruction" to open a web page on an external machine or through other software I think is more complicated and a simple mod I'm afraid.

Comment: 296/5000
forgive the lack of precision,
the cics is interrogated with a 3270 emulator installed on modern laptops on which the browser (chrome, internet-explorer) is present,
it would be enough to have the possibility to start it by passing the link from the emulator,
old ibm 3270 terminals are no longer used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible?  Yes.  Some 3270 emulators can already scan panels and, if they recognize something that looks like a URL, make it a clickable link.  Given that the 3270 protocol allows for hidden fields and the like, you certainly could imagine a 3270 emulator looking for a specifically named and formatted hidden field, and taking an action on that field.  However, doing this would require building the capability into a 3270 emulator, along with adding the field to the 3270 panel.

It might be better to explain what you’re trying to do, because I don’t think this is a good solution to whatever your problem is.  It would be incredibly fragile.

Comment: this way seems interesting:
the value of the link is already displayed on the screen and if the 3270 emulator intercepts it then the user can click on it to open the link,
no changes to the cics program are needed but only a suitable version of the emulator,
probably not open source,
now I'm looking for it, it could be a good solution.
Why do you say that the solution is fragile?
Users use a modern laptop with updated windows 10 system and updated browsers,
on which the emulator is installed to access the historical cics application, which is still valid for the company's work.

Comment: If you control the client completely, this would be safe.  I'm concerned that there are a bunch of moving parts, and any one of them could change and break things.  Also, to clarify:  you aren't trying to get the window to open automatically, just be able to be opened when you click the link?

Comment: yes the window must open at the user's choice by click or with a function key,
the link I believe are within the customer's network therefore protected by the corporate firewall,
the WEB-BROWSER statement option doesn't seem available to me
in this center,
I'm studying the functionality of the emulators

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
the Quick3270 emulator solves the problem,
I verified that clicking (left button) on a field showing a web link the browser is started and the link page is shown
thank you all for the suggestions that directed me to the solution